# how to view the database in listview without replacing the listview text

Tags: android, android-listview

i have a listview with date,so once you run the application it will automatically show the dates(non database item). my question is how can i insert  and view the data from the sqlite database in the same listview.

ex.

```
List item

Current date //default text

text1

List item2

next date //default text

text1
```

here is my Activity codes

```
{
SimpleDateFormat curFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, MMM dd, yyyy"); 
GregorianCalendar date = new GregorianCalendar();

final String[] datas = new String[3];

for (int day = 0; day <7 ; day++) {
    datas[day] = curFormater.format(date.getTime());//to automatically show the date in listview
    date.roll(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, true);
}

}

//  @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_planner);

    lview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView2);
    lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this,datas);


lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);
```

My BaseAdatper

```
    public class ListViewAdapter extends BaseAdapter
{
Activity context;
//String title[];
//String description[];
String mo[];


public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mo.length;
}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

private class ViewHolder {
   // TextView txtViewTitle;
    //TextView txtViewDescription;
    TextView mo;
}

public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewHolder holder;
    LayoutInflater inflater =  context.getLayoutInflater();

    if (convertView == null)
    {
        convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitem_row, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
    //  holder.txtViewTitle = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        //holder.txtViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        holder.mo = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView3);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
    {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    holder.mo.setText(mo[position]);

return convertView;
}
```

My database

```
public class DataListView extends ListActivity {

private ArrayList<String> results = new ArrayList<String>();

private String tableName = DBHelper.tableName;
private SQLiteDatabase newDB;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    openAndQueryDatabase();



    displayResultList();


}
private void displayResultList() {
    TextView tView = new TextView(this);
    tView.setText("This data is retrieved from the database and only 4 " +
            "of the results are displayed");
    //getListView().addHeaderView(tView);

    setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,results));

}

private void openAndQueryDatabase() {
    try {
        DBHelper dbHelper = new DBHelper(this.getApplicationContext());
        newDB = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = newDB.rawQuery("SELECT FirstName, Age FROM " +
                tableName +
                " where Age > 10 LIMIT 4", null);

        if (c != null ) {
            if  (c.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    String firstName = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("FirstName"));
                    int age = c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("Age"));
                    results.add("Name: " + firstName + ",Age: " + age);
                }while (c.moveToNext());
            } 
        }           
    } catch (SQLiteException se ) {
        Log.e(getClass().getSimpleName(), "Could not create or Open the database");
    } finally {
        if (newDB != null) 
            newDB.execSQL("DELETE FROM " + tableName);
            newDB.close();
    }

}
```

}
my database helper

```
public SQLiteDatabase DB;
public String DBPath;
public static String DBName = "sample";
public static final int version = '1';
public static Context currentContext;
public static String tableName = "Resource";


public DBHelper(Context context) {
    super(context, DBName, null, version);
    currentContext = context;
    DBPath = "/data/data/" + context.getPackageName() + "/databases";
    createDatabase();

}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

private void createDatabase() {
    boolean dbExists = checkDbExists();

    if (dbExists) {
        // do nothing
    } else {
        DB = currentContext.openOrCreateDatabase(DBName, 0, null);
        DB.execSQL("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " +
                tableName +
                " (LastName VARCHAR, FirstName VARCHAR," +
                " Country VARCHAR, Age INT(3));");

        DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                tableName +
                " Values ('M','Sing','India',25);");
        DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                tableName +
                " Values ('C','Raje','India',25);");
        DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                tableName +
                " Values ('D','Phonu','Argentina',20);");
        DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                tableName +
                " Values ('V','Veera','EU',25);");
        DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                tableName +
                " Values ('T','Shenoi','Bangla',25);");
        DB.execSQL("INSERT INTO " +
                tableName +
                " Values ('L','Lamha','Australia',20);");
    }


}

private boolean checkDbExists() {
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;

    try {
        String myPath = DBPath + DBName;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null,
                SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
```

Answer (score 0):

I understand your question in a way, that you want to add items to your listview, without removing the already containing items. You can do this by adding items to the adpater and call a notifiychanged to update the listview:

```
lviewAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
lviewAdapter.addAll(model.getItems());
lviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Use the following as member of your class

```
ListAdapter lviewAdapter;
```

In the onCreate method initialize it and set the adapter to the ListView:

```
lviewAdapter = new ListViewAdapter(this,datas);
lview.setAdapter(lviewAdapter);
```

If you want to clear the ListView later before add new items, use the following:

```
lviewAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
lviewAdapter.clear();
lviewAdapter.addAll(model.getItems());
lviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**Update**

Add data from your sql db to the ListView as example:

```
List<String> anotherDataFromSQLDB = new ArrayList<String>();
// Fill data here in list anotherDataFromSQLDB
lviewAdapter.setNotifyOnChange(false);
lviewAdapter.addAll(anotherDataFromSQLDB);
lviewAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

**UPDATE2**

Rewrite you method like this:

```
private void displayResultList() {
   TextView tView = new TextView(this);
   tView.setText("This data is retrieved from the database and only 4 " +
        "of the results are displayed");

   ListViewAdapter adapter = getListView().getAdapter();
   lview.setNotifyOnChange(false);
   lview.addAll(results);
   lview.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

You did setListAdapter(...); before, that replaces the old adapter so the data viewed in the listview before gets replaced. Now with the above method you only add the new data.

Comment: thank you sir,but how can i implement the sqlite database in listview without removing the default text

Comment: what do you mean with default text? I think you want to keep the already inserted data of the List 'datas'. When running the the above example it works, i add an example for you.

Comment: Ok i updated my answer with an example. Does your question also aim on how to access the data of an sqlite db?

Comment: the datas is the default text once i run the app it will  show up automatically in listview. I have data from a database and i want to view the data using listview with a default text which is a datas. i already posted the diagram of my listview above.

Comment: yes sir, because once i viewed the data from database the original text in the listview was replaced by the content of the database

Comment: I already posted may database,thank you sir,sorry i cannot vote

Comment: If my answer has helped you please mark it as solved with the flag on the left of my answer post

Comment: it doesn't work sir,error on these codes   getListView().setNotifyOnChange(false);
   getListView().addAll(results);
   getListView().notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: Yes thats because getListView() is unknown, so replace getListView() with you listview (lview). No offense, but a question, have you written the code by yourself? :)

Comment: no sir im just experimenting if it is possible =),no problem sir its okay, thank you for helping me. can you please help me to achieve this

Comment: i tried but there is no .setNotifyOnChange(false); the one that available is .notifyall() but if i used the getListView() the setnotifyonchange is available but it is mark as an error.,im creating new DB and listview .i will use your instructions above,i will  post the result later, thanks

Comment: If you like, paste your complete code to pastebin etc, so i can rebuild the project and find errors